# Preciso receber valor de uma redirect com with no controller

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Na minha classe `loginController` eu faço o seguinte caminho:

```
return Redirect::to('home')->cookie($nome)->cookie($sessionid)->with('cnpj',$cnpj);
```

Preciso ter esse dado `$cnpj` para repassar da `home.blade.php` para `cliente.blade.php`

Como faço isso? Na home não existe formulário. Só que não quero passar com cookie. Na verdade não quero passar nenhum como cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade quando você utiliza o `Redirect::to('home')->with(variavel)` essa variável já pode ser acessada no seu outro método(home). Para acessa inevitável você tem que usar uma sessão. Você pode pegar o valor do CNPJ a partir desse método: `Session::get('data');`

Você tem que lembrar que o redirecionamento no PHP recarrega a página, realizando uma requisição, gerando uma nova execução do PHP. Por isso a memória das variáveis de antes já não são mais acessíveis.

Pelo seu código postado imagino que esteja usando uma versão antiga do Laravel, recomendo a leitura da documentação do framework:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses